# Postgres select a subset of fields from a JSON object

Tags: json, postgresql

Given some JSON object that has multiple fields eg

```
{a: 1, b: true, c: "some string", d: {foo: "bar"}}
```

How do you select some of those fields as a new JSON object?

I know that you can select a single field:

```
select data->>'a' from '{a: 1, b: true, c: "some string", d: {foo: "bar"}}' as data
```

But how do you select multiple fields into a new JSON object? How do I select just `a` and `b`?

```
select (what?) from '{a: 1, b: true, c: "some string", d: {foo: "bar"}}' as data
```

The result would be:

```
{a: 1, b: true}
```

I'm using 9.6 and a plain JSON column

Comment: `with t(x) as (values('{"a": 1, "b": true, "c": "some string", "d": {"foo": "bar"}}'::json)) select t.*, to_json(j.*) from t, json_to_record(t.x) as j(a int, b bool, d json);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostgreSQL `jsonb_each` function which converting to JSON data to key/value records. Also, you can use `jsonb_typeof` function to get types of JSON elements. For example:

```
select jsonb_typeof(t1.pval) as ptype, t1.pkey, t1.pval 
from jsonb_each('{"a": 1, "b": true, "c": "some string", "d": {"foo": "bar"}}'::jsonb) t1 (pkey, pval)
```

Result:

| ptype | p_key | p_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| number | a | 1 |
| boolean | b | true |
| string | c | "some string" |
| object | d | {"foo": "bar"} |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_to_record` or `json_build_object` PostgreSQL functions.

```
with tmp_table (single_col) as (values (' {"a": 1, "b": true, "c": "some string", "d": {"foo": "bar"}}'::json))
select json_build_object('a', new_json.a, 'b', new_json.b) as new_json_obj from tmp_table, json_to_record(tmp_table.single_col) as new_json(a int, b bool);
```

In above query, `with` with create a temporary table, `temp_table`, with a `single_col`. Then this query will select all the fields from JSON object and create a new JSON object by calling `json_build_object`. And The `json_to_record` function will convert the JSON object into a record with two fileds `a` and `b`.

Here is the result.
[image]